# curl function taking too much time on godaddy

Tags: php, curl

we have upgraded php version 5.3 to 5.4 on godaddy's web hosting. Everything works perfect but CURL functions not executing, if use any of CURL function it takes too much time and whole website stops working for that moment.

while these functions work properly in 5.3, but i dont get why it is taking so much time yet not working. following code making whole website stops working

```
$ch = curl_init("http://sub.example.com/page.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Have you enable curl in php.ini in newer version

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i have created php.ini file added this extension=php_curl.dll , still not working